# Restrict user not to enter more than 100 in text box field in ext-js with out using Regex

Tags: extjs

Restrict user not to enter more than 100 in text box field in ext-js with out using Regex

User can able to enter the values from 0 to 100 (not more than 100) in number field using ext-js. Not using Regular expression.

Please provide any solutions.

Thanks in advance
Nithyn K

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `numberfield` (`Ext.form.field.Number`) and its configuration `maxValue`, which specifies maximal value of the `numberfield`.

Also you should use `minValue: 0`, if you want to specify that as well.

Basic example of the field configuration:

```
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 100,
}
```

and that's it.

`maxValue` documentation can be found [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-maxValue) depending on your ExtJS version.

Comment: i have tried this min and max value but still accepting more than 100 in text field

Comment: A working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q5e). This configuration should work on all ExtJS versions. If it does not work for you, please post your code and ExtJS version.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the max value (or number of digits) in the field you could use

{
xtype: 'numberfield',
minValue: 0,
maxValue: 100,
enforceMaxLength: (number of digits here),
}